# Java8: double-buffer lag

Tags: java, performance, latency, double-buffering

We have noticed a substantial increase in the time it takes for double buffering to complete after java version 8 u40 compared to releases before this one. It became so slow(to the tune of an order of magnitude) that we turn it off for anything above u40 within Java 8. Yes there is flicker(certainly not ideal), but the pace of the user experience doesn't change with a bit of flicker(although the chance for a headache has more than likely increased).

This noticeable lag just came out of the blue right after the target machine installed the affected java release. There were no code changes.

This relates to question:

[Repaint() and double-buffering in java8, bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744773/repaint-and-double-buffering-in-java8-bug)

Has anyone else noticed this issue?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8068529) can help?

Comment: Thanks. That link helps. In response to your question: I am wondering if this has been noticed in the field yet. Also, this attempts to create some visibility for what appears to be something unresolved in the JDK and something that could have wide ranging impact. The release is still quite new. The bugsheet talks about a work around and I will see if it applies here.

Comment: There are some other properties you can fiddle around with [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/2d/flags.html). I agree that it would be good to create some visibility for issues like this, but I don't think SO is a good platform for this. However I don't really know what would be a good platform, just that this Q&A format isn't really it. (And sorry if my initial response came across as rude, I didn't mean it.)

Comment: No worries on the responses. In this business, I've learned you need some thicker skin. A colleague of mine has written up a bug through the Open JDK bug submission portal here: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8131135

Comment: Also, thanks for the flags. I went through them a few weeks ago and we were unable to workaround the issue at the environment level.